# Passing multiple similar options with Commons CLI

Tags: java, command-line-interface, apache-commons-cli

I'm using commons Cli, and was wondering if there was a way to create a number of related options without defining them in the constructor. For example, to input a number of files using --if1, --if2, --if3 e.g without defining:

```
options.addOption("if1".. 
options.addOption("if2"..
options.addOption("if3"..
```

I know that I can work around it by having a single if flag with comma-delimited values for files. However, I am working to a spec that would like the above formatting so it'd be great to exhaust all options before taking that route.

Any comments would be greatly appreciated,

Thanks,
Sam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multivalues option is used usually for such cases, i.e.

```
--if value1 --if value2 --if value3
```

But you might use loop for their creation

```
for (int i=1; i<=3; i++) {
   options.addOption("if" + i);
}
```